# How to set logging level for the module only in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I am using `logging.info` to output information about what my script is doing and I am using `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)` to enable this. And this (`logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)`) also affects other modules I invoke (e.g. SQLAlchemy) causing a way much more verbose output than I want. Can I set the logging level to INFO for my actual script but not for the 3rd-party modules it uses (I'd prefer it to be WARNING for them)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The normal way to do this is to define a logger for the current module - usually based on the file name - at the start of the module, and refer to this throughout.

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def function_that_logs():
    logger.info('will log')   # note, using logger not logging
    logger.debug('will not log')
```

Comment: Please note that you still have to call `logging.basicConfig()` to define a handler for the loggers.